# Argument overwrite doesn't work in scheme/racket

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I am pretty much new to Racket/Scheme. I know basic syntax.
I have written a program for doing cartesian product of list1 with list2. I debugged the program using Dr Racket. It seems that when l2 becomes null, the program doesn't replace l2 with original list i.e. ol2 (which is what I am trying to do).
I am unable to figure out why this is happening.

```
 (define product   (lambda (ol2 l1 l2)  
     (cond  
       [(and (null? l1) (null? l2)) '()]  
       [(null? l2) (product ol2 (rest l1) ol2)]  
       [else (cons (list (first l1) (first l2)) (product ol2 l1 (rest l2)))])))
```

Comment: Is `head` an alias for `first` (or `car`)?

Comment: @AlexisKing Yes, it was an alias for head. I have edited the code for clarity.

Comment: Try using `(require racket/trace)` and using `(trace-define (product ol2 l1 l2) ...)`, then running the function in the REPL. That will likely help make the problem more clear.

Comment: What is `ol2` used for?

Comment: The base case should stop when just `l1` is `empty?` since when `l1` becomes `empty?` `l2` is reset to `ol2`.

Comment: When the second list becomes null. I shift the head pointer of first list and re-send the original list 2. So that the next element of first list can be multiplied individually with all elements of list 2.

Comment: @Sylwester l2 is reset to ol2 when l2 is null and not when l1 is null.  
When l1 is null one can return empty list. However, It is equivalent to the condition when both l1 and l2 is null.

Comment: @aka_007 The last sentence is not quite right. When `l2` is empty and `l1`has one element you get `empty?` `l1` and a non empty `l2`. Then it will pass the base case since `l2` is not `empty?` and the first thing that happens is that it tried to do `first` on the empty list `l1`. That is of course if you started it correctly with both `ol2` and `l2` as the same value. eg `(product '(a b c) '(1 2) '(a b c))`

Comment: @Sylwester So naive of me. Got it. I got the program to work successfully. If you have time, you can write the answer for it and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code:

```scm
(define product   (lambda (ol2 l1 l2)  
     (cond  
       [(and (null? l1) (null? l2)) '()]  
       [(null? l2) (product ol2 (rest l1) ol2)]  ; here l1 gets empty and l2 becomes the same as ol2
       [else (cons (list (first l1) (first l2)) (product ol2 l1 (rest l2)))])))
```

The base case requires both `l1` and `l2` to be `null?`, but since `l2` is replaced by `ol` at the same time as `l1` goes from one element to zero both will never be `null` since `l2` will be the original list.

Then the default case will try to use `first` on the empty list. To fix this, just change the base case to terminate when just `l1` is `null?`:

```scm
(define product   (lambda (ol2 l1 l2)  
     (cond  
       [(null? l1) '()] ; terminate when l1 is null? 
       [(null? l2) (product ol2 (rest l1) ol2)] 
       [else (cons (list (first l1) (first l2)) (product ol2 l1 (rest l2)))])))
```

The use of an extra variable that supposed to be the same wasn't apparent to me or other commenters. Using a named `let` or local helper procedure hides implementation details that users shouldn't have to care about:

```scm
;; with named let
(define (product l1 l2)
  (let product ((l1 l1) (tl2 l2)) 
    (cond  
      [(null? l1) '()] ; terminate when l1 is null? 
      [(null? tl2) (product (rest l1) l2)] 
      [else (cons (list (first l1) (first tl2)) (product l1 (rest tl2)))])))  

;; with local helper procedure
(define (product l1 l2)
  (define (product l1 tl2) 
    (cond  
      [(null? l1) '()] ; terminate when l1 is null? 
      [(null? tl2) (product (rest l1) l2)] 
      [else (cons (list (first l1) (first tl2)) (product l1 (rest tl2)))]))
  ;; call the helper
  (product l1 l2))
```